# How I say way home in esperanto?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-meaning, word-formation, meaning

How I say way home in esperanto?
I find hejmenvojo in google translate but I don't know if this is correct.
If exist more than a way to say this expression the meaning is diferrent?

Comment: Could you provide a full sentence or more context?

Comment: Hi Eduardo, the context is there is a bar that I known and its name is "Caminho de Casa" (like way home/way to home, I think. The original name is portuguese). 
The name of the bar is kind a joke, because when someone asks "Where are you?", the people say "I'm on way home" or "I'm in the way to home".
And I was curious about how to say that in Esperanto.

Comment: Then you'd definitely say "Survoje hejmen", because that's what you would answer if somebody asked you where you are (and if you were actually on your way home). See towards the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La baza formo estas `vojo hejmen`. La `n` bezonatas ĉar temas pri direkto. Jen du ekzemploj el konata fabelo de Fratoj Grimm (tradukitaj de Kabe):

La gepatroj:

```
Ili ne trovos la vojon hejmen kaj ni liberigos nin de ili.
```

La infanoj:

```
ni vidos la panajn pecetojn; ili montros al ni la vojon hejmen. (Kabe)
```

Depende de la kunteksto, ankaŭ eblas `survoje hejmen`:

```
En 1906 ŝi studis en Hispanio kaj survoje hejmen ŝi malsaniĝis en Hendaye.
```

aŭ

```
Sed unue ni iom promenos. Survoje hejmen ni povos iri al ...
```

Comment: I think this is what I looking for!
Because the context is there is a bar that I known and its name is "Caminho de Casa" (like way home/way to home, I think. The original name is portuguese). 
The name of the bar is kind a joke, because when someone asks "Where are you?", the people say "I'm on way home" or "I'm in the way to home".
And I was curious about how to say that in Esperanto.

Comment: Yes, that would be the translation, that would also work in Esperanto. `Kie estas vi? - Survoje hejmen`. If this is the answer you were looking for, you might want to change the accepted answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use it in the sentence:

- *Mi estas **hejme**.* (I'm home.)
- *Mia **hejmo** estas en Nederlando.* (My home is in the Netherlands.)
- *Mi iras **hejmen**.* (I'm going home.)

Comment: Mi kredas ke la demandinto demandas pri “way home”, t.e. “la vojo por iri hejmen”.

Comment: Hi Neil, it's something like that. How to say I'm in the rout/way to home.